# How to obtain packet count of TCP packets?

Tags: python, openflow, ryu

I am retrieving flow statistics using a _flow_stats_reply_handler as demonstrated in the Ryu Traffic Monitor example.

I print using the following:

```
file.write("\n{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{},{}"
                   .format(ev.msg.datapath.id,
                           stat.match['in_port'], stat.match['eth_src'], stat.match['eth_dst'],
                           stat.instructions[0].actions[0].port,
                           stat.packet_count, stat.byte_count,
                           stat.duration_sec, stat.duration_nsec))
```

Note the `stat.packet_count`.

How could I change this to count TCP packets?  I understand there is an `ip_proto` field and a `tcp_flags` field but I don't know how to code the match/count.

Edit:
I have further investigated this and added a flow match to my request flow stats function:

```
def _request_stats(self, datapath):
    self.logger.debug('send stats request: %016x', datapath.id)
    ofp = datapath.ofproto
    parser = datapath.ofproto_parser

    cookie = cookie_mask = 0
    match = parser.OFPMatch(eth_type=0x0800)
    req = parser.OFPFlowStatsRequest(datapath, 0, ofp.OFPTT_ALL, ofp.OFPP_ANY, ofp.OFPG_ANY,
                                     cookie, cookie_mask, match)
    datapath.send_msg(req)
```

This unfortunately still doesn't work, any ideas as to why not would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

You should add more data to your match, like `ip_proto` in order to match with tcp, as you may know, IP protocol number of TCP is 6, for more information about IP Protocol numbers check [Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/List_of_IP_protocol_numbers).

Please use the code below, You don't need to set`tcp_flags` in this case.

```
match = parser.OFPMatch(
    eth_type=0x0800, 
    ip_proto=6, 
    )
```